# deployment issue and git - revert back to prior version

Tags: git, github

I was deploying a change to production this morning, and there was an issue, and the contractor I was working with is unavailable now, despite being available just prior to deployment (eye-roll).

on my production server, I did `git pull origin main`, ran into the issue, and then wanted to try and revert it back. So I found the commit hash of the prior commit before this merge, and did, `git checkout 612aed0227abe33f7fb8eeac5892beb0e2f67034` from the prior merge request.

It gave me this message:

[image]

However, it doesn't seem to have changed anything as I'm getting the same 500 error on production. It should've just checked out that revision right, and then everything should be fine?

I then ran `git checkout main`. Not sure what to do here and I don't want to break anything more than it's already broken.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I somehow got it working on the prior commit, although it's still in a detached head state. I'm not making code modifications here as it's my production environment. I need to work on some fixes and then I'll need to know how to pull from main at the latest commit after that future merge I'll do.

I know enough with git to handle things when they are mostly normal. I use a handful of commands and usually I'm fine, but I don't know what a detached head is or what kind of issues I'm going to run into when I eventually pull from main again.

I don't have CI/CD set up on this project, so my normal deployment process is to SSH into the server, run `git checkout .`, then `git pull origin main`.

That's been working fine until today's fiasco. I now need to know how to get it resolved back to how it was, unless I've irreparably effed things up.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also: we don't know anything about your deployments work. Checking out a specific version on your production server may or may not **deploy** that version (though I'd argue that if it does, then that's a dangerous thing). Do you have any continuous builds? How do you trigger a deployment?

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I don't have any CI/CD setup on this project. I normally merge my PR into main, then I SSH into the server and I run `git checkout .` and then `git pull origin main`. I somehow got it checked out on a prior commit and everything seems to be functioning normally now. I just updated my question, I ultimately will have to fix things, do another PR and merge it, then I need to resolve this detached head state and get it back to the main branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Theory

> I don't know what a detached head is

When your git repo in the detached head state it just means that your working tree (the actual files on the hard drive) is not on a branch. That all it means. It's not an error state.

> what kind of issues I'm going to run into when I eventually pull from main again

If you modified files to get your code working on the prod server then it is likely you have **not** committed them back to `origin`.

This means that when you try to get the changes from `origin` next time you will likely get merge conflicts (because the local fixes and the remote fixes are likely be in the same files and probably even the same changes [plus new features]).

## Practice

I think for your next 'deployment' you could follow these steps:

1. Save, just in case, any locally made changes:

   1. `git switch -b better_safe_than_sorry_1`
   2. `git add --all`
   3. `git commit -am 'PROD server as of <date_here>'`
   4. Now we're ready to get `main`
2. `git switch main`
3. `git pull`

Alternatively you could:

1. `git fetch origin` - this will download the changes made remotely but it will not apply them to your current working tree.
2. `git reset --hard origin/main` - this says: forget any¹ changes made locally and make my current working tree to what the local `origin/main` is. Since we did a `fetch` just before, after this your working tree should be identical with `main` on `origin`. **This will delete any changes you made locally.**

---

¹ = changes to the files git tracks - files from `.gitignore` will not be deleted. (BTW. The same applies to your `pulls` - any 'temp' files that git doesn't track are not changed by your `pull`s.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I should've been more clear that I'm modifying files on production. I always go back to my local, make the change on a separate branch, push back to remote branch, then PR and merge into main. Then I log back into the production server, do a `git pull origin main`, and usually that doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *reset* your branch to that earlier commit before the pull commit, then do a hard reset:

```
# from your branch
git reset --hard 612aed02
```

What your checkout command did was to put the branch into the detached HEAD state.  Temporarily the head of the branch was pointing to commit `612aed02`, but the true HEAD of the branch was unchanged.

Comment: Ok, Maybe that's fine for the time being. I just updated my answer. For now I just need the app to work in production, which it seems to be. Later I'll need to merge a fix into main, then get my production server back to pulling from main and not in a detached head state. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The detached HEAD is not pointing to any branch but points to a specific commit. what you get back from `git branch` command?

Comment: @Talkhak1313 Well if you `git branch` from a detached head state, then you'll create a bona fide new branch.